# I want to control volume in Windows 8, at the same time to show volume bar

Tags: c++, microsoft-metro

In Windows7, I always use endpoint interface to control system volume. It works well.
But in Windows 8, I want to control volume at the same time to show volume bar in Metro style.
Also I want to control brightness value at the same time to show brightness bar in Metro style.
I use Visual C++ 2010. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm able to realize some functions of my question.
I use WM_APPCOMMAND, volume progress bar can display in Windows 8.
For example:

```
::SendMessage(this->GetSafeHwnd(), WM_APPCOMMAND, 0x30292, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP * 0x10000);
```

But I can't control brightness bar to display with adjusting it.

Comment: Then, I still get Endpoint volume's value so that I judge current volume.